# Trouble with WHERE EXIST subquery of a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am trying to run a Left Join in the MS Access SQL. I am trying to Left Join my "OldPE" table to New "1 PE" table and update my column labeled "Line Num". There is no primary key in these tables so I am linking them through a series of conditions. Here is my code so far (excuse the poor formatting I am new and still learning SQL).

```
UPDATE [1 PE]
LEFT JOIN OldPE ON ([1 PE].SumRes = OldPE.SumRes)  
AND ([1 PE].[Project Code] = OldPE.[Project Code]) 
AND ([1 PE].[DeptID] = OldPE.[DeptID]) 
AND ([1 PE].[Res Code] = OldPe.[Res Code]) 
AND ([1 PE].[Explain The Cost] LIKE OldPE.[Explain The Cost]) 
AND ([1 PE].Notes LIKE OldPE.Notes)  
SET [1 PE].[Line Num] = [OldPE].[Line Num];
```

There are a lot of rows that have null or blank values in their "Explain The Cost" and "Notes" columns. I used a like statement because some of the notes that I want together vary slightly due to spelling mistakes and such. However now that I use the "like" it won't return the rows with a null value for these columns. The SQL code wont accept a WHERE EXISTS (I may also just be writing it wrong).

How do I get these null values to still be returned while using the Like command

Comment: I suspect that `LIKE` is not what you hope it is: [Like Operator (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208897(v=office.12).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNULL to join back to the original value if it is null.  (This will include the null values in the results.)

```
 AND ([1 PE].[Explain The Cost] LIKE ISNULL(OldPE.[Explain The Cost],[1 PE].[Explain The Cost]))
```

Comment: That will work, but will perform a full-table scan. If these columns are indexed it would be better to perform the LIKE along with an OR checking for a NULL value.

Comment: @Grayson - hmmm... not been my experience with most SQL platforms and `COALESCE`, most of them expect it and can optimize for it better than multiple operations, but Jet is not a very good compiler and I have not used it much recently so you might be right.